# Going around Voltage Limitation on Battery for Steppers?

Tags: battery, stepper-motor

Am building a device that will use two stepper motors and a servo. One of the main requirements, is that the on-board **battery** cannot exceed 9.6 volts.
The stepper motors have not been picked yet, and thus I have the option of choosing one with a lower voltage.

Which method would be the best:

- Use two 12v stepper motors with a 9.6 volt battery, and simply have them run at lower voltage.
- Or, Use two 12v steppers, and use a DC to DC voltage booster to increase voltage to 12v. ( I don't know how well this would work, regarding constant current and whatnot.)
- Or, Use two 6v steppers, and use a ~6v battery. (Not fond of this idea, as 6v steppers seem to have much different specs than normal Nema17 12v ones. However, I would still use them if needed.)

Answer (score 1):

I use Step-Up breakouts from SparkFun and Pololu all the time. They provide a consistent, continuous flow at the desired voltage. I recommend [this one](https://www.pololu.com/product/2117), or if you need more than 1.4A current than [this one](https://www.pololu.com/product/2568). Beware that these components can be easily damaged by heat, and too much will damage the Step-Up, causing it to actually *lower* the voltage. As long as you don't burn the thing it will provide more than useful.